# Castle Windsor can't inject an array of interface types

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a class that takes an array of interfaces in the constructor:

```
public class Foo<T1, T2> : IFoo<T1, T2>
{
    public Foo(IBar[] bars)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My container registration looks as follows:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Pick().FromAssemblyNamed("...")
                    .WithService.FirstInterface());
container.AddComponent("foo", typeof(IFoo<,>), typeof(Foo<,>));
```

I have several implementations of IBar, and the container can definately locate them, as calling `ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IBar>()` works fine.

**However, if I try to get an instance of IFoo, it throws an exception saying it couldn't satisfy the deoendency... "which was not registered".**

If I change the constructor to take a single instance of IBar it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the ArrayResolver:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Comment: @Ben: not currently, but you may suggest it on uservoice: http://castle.uservoice.com : "Add subresolvers via xml config"

Comment: Or better yet fork the source http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl and implement it ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me as well. The internet seems to be full of people reinventing custom versions of this class...

Comment: If I didn't register with WithService then the ArrayResolver didn't resolve the array, but WithService fixes that.