# Castle Windsor Dependency Injection with Multiple Concrete Implementations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Is there a method for Castle Windsor to inject multiple concrete implementations of a single interface into a constructor?

I want to do something like this:

```
class Some
{
   public Some(IService[] services)
   {
      services.Each(s => s.DoSomething(this));
   }
}
```

Note, at this level I do not have access to the `IWindsorContainer` and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057977/castle-windsor-cant-inject-an-array-of-interface-types/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=257